# How to switch off my internal mic?

Tags: windows-7, audio, microphone, hp-pavilion

I have bought a Sonicgear microphone. It gets recognized by my computer, but when I try to record using OneNote, sounds from my internal mic are only recorded. I have an HP Pavilion Laptop and it comes with an IDT audio driver. I muted the Microphone, Integrated Microphone Array and Stereo Mix, and only left Master and external microphone on, but still only the internal microphone is being recorded.

Is there any way to switch off my internal mic and keep only my external one on?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: [disable](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows7/ht/disable-device-windows-7.htm) it in device manager?

Comment: @smc In device manager the michrophone and speakers etc.. are shown collectively. IDT High Definition Audio Codec, ATI High Definition Audio Device and AnvSoft Virtual Sound Device are the only devices listed under Sound, video and game controllers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### To set a default recording device system-wide:

- Click on the Start button and, in the search box, type 'Change sound card settings' or 'Manage audio devices' without the quotes. In the results, click on the link with the same name. This will bring the Sound window.
- To set a device as default for recording, go to the Recording tab in the Sound window. In the Recording tab, click on the desired default recording device (ex. a certain microphone) and click on the Set Default button.

*See the screenshot below:*

[image]

#### To resolve the issue with just OneNote:

- Open your Onenote,
- Go to File > Options > Audio & Video and set your preferred sound input there.

*See the screenshot below:*

[image]

Comment: This only resolves the issue with OneNote. What should I do with other apps such as Skype?

Comment: You can either configure every application separately or [change default recording device](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-change-default-playback-recording-audio-device). Skype has its own settings, btw

Comment: Could you please add the above comment to your answer. It worked.

Comment: @Sanoo: answer updated.